# How do I insert code examples into an HTML file?

Tags: html

I want to place an example of code without the tags being processed?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Xmp tag will work:

```
<xmp>
   ...code...
</xmp>
```

ETA:
As of this writing this still works in all major browsers, but as others have pointed out it has officially been obsoleted in HTML5 [[link]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features). Browsers could stop rendering it any day without warning or notice and it should be avoided for production sites. Still, there is no replacement that doesn't involve HTML encoding your string manually or using iframe trickery. It still has a place in *my* personal utility page tool-belt, but I would not consider it for a client.

Comment: <code> tag would be most appropriate, since the OP did ask for "example of code".
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code

Comment: Note: the `xmp` element is obsolete, don't use it! https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 22):

The `<pre>` tag allows you to display text with whitespaces and line breaks as-is. Also, code must be entity-encoded:
For example, the code sample

```
 <html>
   <head><title></title></head>
   <body></body>
 </html>
```

will become

```
<pre>&lt;html>
  &lt;head>&lt;title>&lt;/title>&lt;/head>
  &lt;body>&lt;/body>
&lt;/html></pre>
```

`<` encodes into `&lt;` `&` encodes into `&amp;`

PHP `htmlentities` does the job:

```
<pre><?php echo htmlentities($code) ?></pre>
```

`<textarea>` does the job too: it also allow the code to be copied.

Comment: The entity encoding is the important part for getting HTML tags to show up literally in the document. The `<pre>` just affects how it's formatted.

Comment: I think he doesn't want to escape the elements in the example (doesn't want to convert `<html>` to `&lt;html>`).

Comment: Don't use htmlentities() because not all browser support all the HTML entities that this functions spits out.  Use htmlspecialchars() and make sure your page's encoding is set correctly.

Comment: and use &gt; for >

Answer (score 9):

To present code in HTML typically one would use the `<code>` tag.

Your question isn't very clear, and I don't know what you mean by "without the tags being processed". If you're saying that you want to present a fragment of HTML as code in an HTML page (for example), then you need to "escape" the HTML tags so that the web client doesn't attempt to parse them.

To do this, you should use the entity `&gt;` for the greater-than angle bracket, and `&lt;` for the less-than bracket.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<xmp></xmp>
```

or

```
<code></code>
```

for exemple:

```
<pre>
     <xmp><!-- your html code --></xmp>
</pre>

<pre>
     <code><!-- your html code --></code>
</pre>
```

bye

Answer (score 2):

put it in a text area, its an html tag that will prevent all text inside him to be rendered

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an XHTML `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration, then you could use `CDATA` sections:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
 <head>
     <title>My Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>Example!</h1>
     <pre><code>
     <![CDATA[
         <div>
             <ol>
                 <li>a</li>
                 <li>b</li>
                 <li>c</li>
             </ol>
         </div>
     ]]>
     </code></pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note that you'll want to use a `.xhtml` file extension and you'll want to consider serving these documents with a `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` header.

Comment: In fact, doctype doesn't matter for the parsing of the page, only `Content-type` HTTP header does.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is just converting all your ‘<’ and ‘>’ to ‘&lt’ and ‘&gt’ respectively

Answer (score 0):

Beyond putting your code in 'pre' tags and escaping th '<' and'>' you may want to look as syntax highlighting. A good library for this was written by Alex Gorbatchev.

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 0):

Run the HTML you wish to display though [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to properly escape the code you wish to display if you're using PHP.  Do NOT use [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) because your browser will choke on extended characters.  Just make sure your page's encoding is set correctly in the `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` if you are outputting `UTF-8` for example.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use textarea with this way.

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="25">
    <form action=".. " method="post" id="postForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Customer Name" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>                                     
    </textarea>
```

**Note** this use Bootstrap 3, if you want pure html remove textarea class and rows attribute.

Answer (score -2):

Make it a comment.

```
<p>This will be rendered.</p>
<!-- from here on, this is a comment
<p>This won't be rendered.</p>
end of comment -->
<p>This will be rendered too.</p>
```

Comment: I think @Kevin Garcia wants the HTML code to be visible in the browser.

Comment: I think he meant something like <pre>, but then actaully skipping the tags

Answer (score -2):

This works like a gem. I am trying to get the code on the HTML page. We need to use the combo as below. I have tested this as well.

```
    <xpm>
        <pre>
        #include&lt;stdio.h&gt;
        void fun(){
            printf("%s","yooo");
        }
        fun();
         </pre>
    </xpm>
```